# Error When installing FileZilla in XAMPP

Tags: xampp, filezilla

When I try to install Filezilla on xampp, I get this message:
    
7:55:33 AM  [filezilla]     Setting Service Name...
    
7:55:33 AM  [filezilla]     Setting Service Display Name...
    
7:55:33 AM  [filezilla]     Installing service...
    
7:55:33 AM  [filezilla]     Service was NOT (un)installed!

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: There should be an error log somewhere telling you why it was not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Start the FileZilla Service First in XAMPP. 
Then it will popup telling to select whether is it Private or Public Network. 
After selecting it, press OK. 
Once it has Filezilla has started, Stop the FileZilla service.

Then, Click on the 'X' Filezilla to install. By right, it should be able to be installed into your PC.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to delete the Service Registry key, so open REGEDIT and go to this path. 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet' "filezilla Server Or filezillaserver" Export Key and Delete key. Then restart your computer. After that, you must run XAMPP in Administrator mode. Click the install button.

1 ST STEP
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/524So.png)

Then
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy9Py.png)

After Restart
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igZqh.png)

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cskn7.png)